# Is $\{a^n b^n c^{2n} \mid n \geqslant 0\}$ a context-free language?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

I tried to solve this excersize but get two different answers

I know that we can do homomorphism 
$$
  h(0)→a,h(1)→b,h(2)→cc
$$
and  $h^{-1}(L)$ = {$0^n 1^n 2^n | n \geqslant 0$ } that **is not CFL**

But, if we will do other homomorphism $$g(a)→0, g(b)→0, g(c)→1$$
so $g(L)= \{0^{2n} 1^{2n} \mid n \geqslant 0 \}$ **is CFL**.

What wrong with the second option?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Hi, What is wrong with the way that I asked?

Comment: There is a certain lack of context. Besides, what you wrote is hard to read. For instance, you write $->$ instead of $\to$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos OK, I fixed it.. Is there more problems?

Comment: In order to typeset sets using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), you should type `$\{...\}$`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the second option except that you cannot conclude anything from it. To be precise, you are trying to use the fact that context-free languages are closed under homomorphisms and inverses of homomorphisms.

Your first argument goes as follows: if $L$ were context-free, then $h^{-1}(L)$ would also be context-free, which is not the case. Thus $L$ is not context-free.

Your second attempt is: if $L$ were context-free, then $g(L)$ would also be context-free. But since  $g(L)$ is context-free, there is no contradiction and you cannot conclude that $L$ is not context-free.